# Button clicked and held down on NumericUpDown control : How to stop ctrl speeding up

Tags: visual-c++, controls, effects

I'm using a NumericUpDown control; every time I click the up or down button I have to convert the number in the control to a 2'Complelent number and send it via serial1.Write with some data in order to write the number, address to a DDS Module.  The problem is it works for about 10 - 15 numbers when held down continuously then the control speeds up to the point that I can't even see what numbers are being sent with the result that I'm getting corrupt data after that time and the module is not registering the numbers in the DDS Module.  Does anyone know how to slow the overall control down to a steady speed.
I appreciate any assistance I can get.
Thanks
Mel

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.accelerations?view=netcore-3.1#remarks

> Remarks
> The Accelerations property can be used to increase the speed with which the NumericUpDown moves through a large set of numbers when the user holds the up or down arrow, either with the keyboard or with the mouse. Setting this property will decrease the number of ValueChanged events that occur depending on the Increment and Seconds property values specified for each NumericUpDownAcceleration object in the collection. The NumericUpDownAcceleration objects contained in the collection are sorted by their NumericUpDownAcceleration.Seconds property.

Comment: Vlad,                                                                                                                                         
Thanks for the response.  It took a bit to figure the relationship between the acceleration and time but final result was good. Mel